# PHP check if date is 30 days in the past

Tags: php, sql, date, back

I'm having a bit of a problem here.

I insert a date into the database: `date_last_applied`.

I can just call this by using `$row['date_last_applied']`, of course. Now, I need to check if this inserted date was **30 days ago** and if so, execute an action.

```
$query = "SELECT date_last_applied FROM applicants WHERE memberID='$id'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $date = strtotime($row['date_last_applied']);

}
```

That's about all I have.. I tried some things, but they all failed. :(

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
if ($date < strtotime('-30 days'))
```

If you are **only** performing actions on dates older than 30 days, you should use Marco's solution.

Comment: PHP solution is correct and perhaps OP needed that. +1 for you! :)

Comment: +1 for yours as well... he wasn't quite clear on what he needed.  :-D  For all I know, he could have wanted something *exactly* 30 days ago, but I can't think of a time when anyone has needed that.

Comment: For this solution to work, `$date` has to be a timestamp. If your date is not a timestamp, use this `strtotime($date) < strtotime('-30 days')`

Answer (score 11):

You could do it via SQL getting only dates in last 30 days

```
SELECT date_last_applied 
FROM applicants 
WHERE memberID = your_id
  AND date_last_applied BETWEEN
      DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()
```

or older than 30 days

```
SELECT date_last_applied 
FROM applicants 
WHERE memberID = your_id
  AND date_last_applied < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Comment: I'm also executing a code for when it's not 30 days ago. I need this solution for an other project though, so thanks!

Comment: Ok... I now need this code, but it definitely does not work.. :/
I'm using the `time()` format, which might cause this (although I think it shouldn't). It just always returns positive, whatever I do.

Comment: @Aart: I don't understand where you're using `time()`; my query return s records where date in database is between current date/time and 30 days ago... so it's using days... if you use only time it cannot work... Let me understand better...

Comment: Well, I'm inserting into the database: `INSERT INTO applicants (date_last_applied) VALUES ('" . time() . "')`. Now I'm retrieving that date, using `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM DDFS_applicants WHERE date_last_applied < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
 echo $row['id_member'];`
but it's not working. :( It always returns positive. Same with your other code (BETWEEN).

Comment: 'DDFS_applicants' should have been 'applicants', but that isn't the fault in my code. Also: with "returns positive", I mean that it gives the id_member of every entry.

Comment: @Aart: I think the error is because you're saving only time in your database, so how system can check date too `(INTERVAL 1 DAY)`?

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean. `time()` is years, months, dayes and so on, right? But do you have a suggestion on how to make it work?