# PHP WordPress - check if a date falls within the last 30 days

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I've been handed a WordPress file that displays custom events. It's been setup so that events are split into 2 categories based on if the date assigned to the event is in the past or future.

What I've been asked to do is add a 3rd category of "Recently Past" (*If the event happened within the past 30 days from today's date*).

I've looked at other answers on here like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080760/php-check-if-date-is-30-days-in-the-past), which makes me think I need to use something like `'value' => date('Ymd', strtotime('today - 30 days')),` but if this is correct, how would I stop the "Recently Past" events from also showing up in the "Past" events category?

In case it's helpful, it's also using Advanced Custom Fields as part of the query, which you can see in the code below `if ( get_sub_field('show_events') == 'past' ) {`
I know how to add an additional query there, so can amend that `if` block to have an extra query. It's the array comparisons I'm stuck on.

```
<?php 

// Date is past                                
$meta_query_past = array(
  array(
    'key' => 'event_date',
    'value' => date('Ymd'),
    'type' => 'DATE',
    'compare' => '<='
  )
);

// Date is future
$meta_query_future = array(
  array(
    'key' => 'event_date',
    'value' => date('Ymd'),
    'type' => 'DATE',
    'compare' => '>='
  )
);

if ( get_sub_field('show_events') == 'past' ) {
  $meta_query = $meta_query_past;
  $attending = "We attended this event";
  $show_events = 'past';
  $sort_order = 'DESC';
} else {
  $meta_query = $meta_query_future;
  $attending = "We're attending this event";
  $show_events = 'future';
  $sort_order = 'ASC';
}

$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'event',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'order' => $sort_order,
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
  'meta_key' => 'event_date',
  'meta_query' => $meta_query
);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the solution to my own question just in case it helps anyone with a similar issue.

```
<?php 
// Date is past, but not within the last 30 days
$meta_query_past = array(
  array(
    'key' => 'event_date',
    'value' => date('Ymd', strtotime('-30 days')),
    'type' => 'DATE',
    'compare' => '<'
  )
);
// Date is recent
$meta_query_recent = array(
  'relation' => 'AND',
  // Date is more than date 30 days ago 
  array(
    'key' => 'event_date',
    'value' => date('Ymd', strtotime('-30 days')),
    'type' => 'DATE',
    'compare' => '>='
  ),
  // Date is less than todays date
  array(
    'key' => 'event_date',
    'value' => date('Ymd'),
    'type' => 'DATE',
    'compare' => '<'
  )
);
$meta_query_future = array(
  'relation' => 'OR', 
  // Date is future
  array(
    'key' => 'event_date',
    'value' => date('Ymd'),
    'type' => 'DATE',
    'compare' => '>='
  ),
  // Date is empty
  array(
    'key' => 'event_date',
    'value' => '',
    'compare' => '='
  )
);

if ( get_sub_field('show_events') == 'past' ) {
  $meta_query = $meta_query_past;
  $attending = "We attended this event";
  $show_events = 'past';
  $sort_order = 'DESC';
} elseif ( get_sub_field('show_events') == 'recent' ) {
  $meta_query = $meta_query_recent;
  $attending = "We recently attended this event";
  $show_events = 'recent';
  $sort_order = 'DESC';
} else {
  $meta_query = $meta_query_future;
  $attending = "We're attending this event";
  $show_events = 'future';
  $sort_order = 'ASC';
}

$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'event',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'order' => $sort_order,
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
  'meta_key' => 'event_date',
  'meta_query' => $meta_query
);
?>
```